# NavigationDrawer(SlidingMenu): which one is best?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to incorporate  a youtube like drawer navigation drawer for both(left,right) sides. AFAIK android apis don't provide means for the right-to-left drawer functionality. There're quite a lot of implementations out there([sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)) which do.

This sliding menu feature seems to present a performance issue. Should I try to rewrite original NavigationDrawer, which I expect to be the least performance-impact solution, or there is another performance-optimal library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last version of [SupportLibrary](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) there is a [NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) in Android.

Comment: I'm surprised Google doesn't put this  navigation drawer in new Google I/O 2013 app, which have responsive UI!

Answer (score 3):

I would choose NavigationDrawer. I used both and I find NavigationDrawer smoother. If you try to mimic google UX then with NavigationDrawer should be enought for your needs.

I recently made a project/demo to implement NavigationDrawer with ActionBarSherlock for pre Honeycomb devices because I need for an app.

[SherlockNavigationDrawer impl](https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer)

Another thing to take in mind is that if you use NavigationDrawer try to avoid Tabs because all the tabs items could fit perfectly as a listview in NavigationDrawer.

Comment: SherlockNavigationDrawer means you ported google NavigationDrawer to work with ABS or it's your own implementation which looks like original NavigationDrawer?

Comment: @LOG_TAG the first one, I ported google's NavigationDrawer to work with ABS.

Answer (score 3):

Actually NavigationDrawer supports drawers on both edges.

You have to supply the two drawer views inside your layout xml; one with gravity:left and one with gravity:right.

Then, in your Activity you call setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED) on your DrawerLayout object.

This will enable swiping either from left or right edge.

Answer (score 2):

@Michał The question is actually implementation of both left as well as the right drawer.

@midnight NavigationDrawer right now only implements one-sided menu which you can place either on the left or the right. If you want to implement the other pane also you can make your content layout as [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html).
This was also added to the latest support library along with the NavgationDrawer. For an implemented example you can look at the newest Hangouts app on how they are using it. This layout will probably suit your purposes better rather than rewriting the NavigationDrawer. In any case i'd hold off on re-writing it since it is the first release of the Layout and may undergo changes fairly quickly.